# Size Div to be as Large as the Image Within It

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my div as big as the image within it.  However, it doesn't work.  And when I Google it I find results for fitting the image size to the div.  I want the other way around.

Here's my code:

```css
.backgroundimage {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundimage">
  <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's a picture of how large the div is right now:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A `<div>` is by default `display: block`**, which means it will take the entire 100% width of its parent which will extend to the entire page's width in your case. If you need your div width to flow according to the contents inside it, you need to change it to `display:inline-block`

```
.backgroundimage {
  display:inline-block
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is the pos:absolute of the youtube-iframe.

```
.backgroundimage {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 46px;
    width: 505px;
    height: 329px;
}
.Youtube {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

I just put together a codepen here: http://codepen.io/mtness/pen/kkvoaQ

It would be IMHO better to fit the youtube-iframe neatly into the backgroundImage-div, and have this positioned via margins or else.

Comment: apart from that, the dimensions of the youtube-iframe and the background image do not match. In the Pen, i adjusted the size of the youtube-iframe accordingly.